# Set a different color to a row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the below [code](http://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-plot-examples-with-matplotlib-pyplot) we can pick any pair `(name and age)` and make the histogram of them:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill','lisa','jose'],
    'age':[23,78,22,19,45,33,20],
    'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
    'state':['california','dc','california','dc','california','texas','texas'],
    'num_children':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
    'num_pets':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
})
df.plot(kind='bar',x='name',y='age')
plt.show()
```

What I want to do is to make the bar for **Lisa** in red color, and the rest of them is unchanged.

How to set the color to a certain row? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs of df.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

> DataFrame.plot(x=None, y=None, kind='line', ax=None, subplots=False,
>   sharex=None, sharey=False, layout=None, figsize=None, use_index=True,
>   title=None, grid=None, legend=True, style=None, logx=False,
>   logy=False, loglog=False, xticks=None, yticks=None, xlim=None,
>   ylim=None, rot=None, fontsize=None, colormap=None, table=False,
>   yerr=None, xerr=None, secondary_y=False, sort_columns=False,
>   **kwds)

We can see that the function takes **kwds (last line of the quote)

Looking further:

> [...]
>   `**kwds` : keywords
>   Options to pass to matplotlib plotting method

The plotting method you call is `plt.bar()`, whose [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) says:

> ```
> Other Parameters: 
>     color : scalar or array-like, optional
>     The colors of the bar faces.
>
>     edgecolor : scalar or array-like, optional
>     The colors of the bar edges.
> ```

So, you can pass a list or an array of the desired colors to the method, like so:

```
color = 7*['blue']
color[-2] = 'red'

df.plot(kind='bar',x='name',y='age', color=color)
plt.show()
```

[image]