# Changing Colors of the Plot of A DataFrame of a Single Line in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

**Problem:**

Suppose I have a PANDAS data frame titled, `recorded_values_of_accelerometer` which appears as a one column by 22272 row table in the figure below:

[image: ImageOne: DataFrame]

Now, suppose I need to plot this table using `recorded_values_of_accelerometer.plot()`. However, I need certain rows in the plot to be of a particular color. Say, rows 78 to 295 should appear red instead of blue. Running, `recorded_values_of_accelerometer.plot()` we have something like:

[image: Image2: Graphed Image]

How do I do that?

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to mimic the solution to this thread:
[Set a different color to a row of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253229/set-a-different-color-to-a-row-of-dataframe)

I did the following:

```py
colorOfPoints = 22272 * ['red']

for values in range(78, 295):
    colorOfPoints[values] = 'blue'
    
recorded_values_of_accelerometer.plot(color = colorOfPoints)
```

However, it just makes the entire plot blue (the most recent color) instead of only columns 78 to 295.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with the `DataFrame.plot()`.
Just use Matplotlib API like the following example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
...
s = frame[frame.columns[0]]
p.plot(s[:78], 'b')
p.plot(s[78:], 'r')
p.legend(s.name)
p.show()
```